# How to set button invisible android

Tags: android, button, invisible

So I tried to make A button invisible, I searched first the forum for the answer and tryed it but it just doesn't work.

```
int level=0;
    try{
        String FILENAME = "TowerFile";
        FileInputStream fos = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        byte[] b = new byte[1];
        fos.read(b);
        fos.close();
        if(new String(b).equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
            level=1;
        }
        if(new String(b).equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
            level=2;
        }
        if(new String(b).equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
            level=3;
        }
        if(new String(b).equalsIgnoreCase("4")){
            level=4;
        }
        if(new String(b).equalsIgnoreCase("5")){
            level=5;
        }
    }catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);



    if(level==1){
        button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

So I first get A variabel out of my file, and then I want to make A button invisable depending on the output. I get the wright number out of my file but it doesn't do anything, I also did 0 and gone but nothing works

Comment: can you paste your xml file too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
buttonName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This is better than (View.INVISIBLE) cause the button doesn't get any space from the layout. If you want to make the button another time visible just use:

```
buttonName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 5):

try to do like this

```
button1.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: try that code without if block if and let me know what happen

Comment: Yes without the if statement it doesn't appear

Comment: oh it shows there is problem in you logic that level is not get assigned by the correct value please check your code new String(b).equalsIgnoreCase("1") assigning level or not

Comment: Yes I found it to but I am using the same method for my languege and that works

Comment: means your proble get resolved or not if resolved then set type of question close

Comment: or is there any other issue raised

Answer (score 1):

The code you written for making button invisible is correct. Check whether the variable **level** is **1** or not.

Answer (score 0):

The following code runs on the main/UI thread to hide a button. If you want the button to be transparent, please change the code View.GONE to View.INVISIBLE.

Home is the context.

```
try {

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {                         
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
    } catch (Exception e) {

    Toast.makeText(Home.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

If you like the answer, please vote. Thanks